# Xpath match current node or one of child nodes

Tags: xpath

I'm having a trouble creating Xpath for following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="tablesorter">
<tbody>     
    <tr class="tr_class">
                    <td>{some td info}</td>
                    <td>{some td info}</td>                    
                    <td>
                        <span class="span1">
                            <span class="span2">Out</span>
                            <span class="span3">SMTH</span>
                            <span class="span4">Out</span>
                        </span>
                    </td>   
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr_class">
                    <td>{some td info}</td>
                    <td>{some td info}</td>                    
                    <td>In</td> 
    </tr>

    <tr class="tr_class">
                    <td>{some td info}</td>
                    <td>{some td info}</td>                    
                    <td>In</td> 
    </tr>   

</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

What I want is to create Xpath that will return me content of each third td node (if it doesn't have children) or a content of it's span that has class="span2".
For example, for this html it should return

```
Out,In,In
```

I have Xpath that will return needed span node, it looks like:

```
//table[@class = 'tablesorter']//td[3]/descendant::*[@class='span2']/text()
```

and I have Xpath that will return me simple content of each 3d td nodes:

```
//table[@class = 'tablesorter']//td[3][count(descendant::*)=0]/text()
```

But I need only one Xpath, because for me it is necessary to have a right ordering of 'In' or 'Out' values (their ordering in the table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it, no idea how robust it will be for your "corpus":

```
//table[@class="tablesorter"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/descendant::text()[normalize-space(.)!=""]
```

`['Out', 'In', 'In']`

---

**Update**

```
//table[@class="tablesorter"]/tbody/tr/td[3]/descendant::text()[normalize-space(.)!=""][parent::td or parent::span[@class="span2"]]
```

Comment: unfortunately, that't not the right answer - it will produce right output, but not in a right way - it doesn't check @class of nodes.

Comment: Which nodes do you want the class checked for?

Comment: It works fine with the sample you've provided. You may need to expand your sample to demonstrate how it isn't working

Comment: MattH, thank you for you answer - I updated example to show more complicated case.